# How many user settings can be stored in 4 bytes?

Tags: binary, hex, settings, preferences, long-integer

I have limited storage being 2 x 2 bytes.  I need to store as many (On/Off) user preferences within this byte space as possible.

My calculation so far is a total of 20 user settings by incrementing by a multiple of 2 e.g.

```
First 2 Byte space

    Option A ON = 1
    Option B ON = 2
    Option C On = 4
    Option D On = 8
    Option E On = 16
    Option F On = 32
    Option G On = 64
    Option H On = 128
    Option I On = 256

Second 2 byte space:

    Option J On = 1
    K=2
    L=4
    M=8
    N=16
    O=32
    P=64
    Q=128
    R=256
```

And from this I can work out what the user has enabled or disabled across all 20 options (Assuming 00000000 / 00000000 is nothing selected).

My question to you is, is 20 the maximum amount of options a user can set using 2 x 2 bytes to store their state or is there a more efficient way?

Thanks

Comment: Four bytes?  32 bits.  32 on-off switches.  Not sure where you got 20, unless that's 20 hex (which corresponds to 32 decimal).

Comment: I was looking at combining the options so no overlapping. I will be using bit masks: someSetting | someOtherSetting etc.  I think I am getting my head around it.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: Note that `I` isn't actually in the first byte.  `I` is the first bit in the *second* byte.